# enum でセレクトボックスを表示させてインデックス番号をDB に保存したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

## 環境

- macOS 10.15.6
- Ruby 2.5.7
- Rails 5.2.3

## 参考にしたURL

[【Rails】enumチュートリアル](https://pikawaka.com/rails/enum)
[【Rails】enumとは? enumを用いてselectボックスを作ってみた - Qiita](https://qiita.com/clbcl226/items/3e832603060282ddb4fd)
[【Rails】enumを使用したセレクトボックスの実装とDBへの保存 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/y-suna/items/1f5f34c6289fd88199a5)
[【Rails】Enumってどんな子？使えるの？ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ozackiee/items/17b91e26fad58e147f2e)
[f.selectで生成されるoptionタグを改変する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ATORA1992/items/fc6217412c5bc004ac6c)

## 実現したいこと

1. 投稿時の:expense カラムのセレクトボックスの選択肢をenum で登録した値(type1, type2, type3)で表示したい

```html
# 実現したいセレクトボックスの形
<select>
  <option value="1">type1</option>
  <option value="2">type2</option>
  <option value="3">type3</option>
</select>
```

2. DB に保存する値はセレクトボックスのvalue の値(1, 2, 3)をInteger 型で保存したい

```rb
# 実現したいDB 保存の形
{
    :name => "name",
    :expense => 1 # enum で登録したvalue値のインデックス番号のInteger 型
}
```

## 問題

DB 保存時に`'1' is not a valid expense` エラーで保存ができません(はじめの数字はenum で定義したvalue値に対応するインデックス番号)

## 状態

```rb
# schema.rb
  create_table "destinations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "expense", default: 0
  end
```

```rb
# controller
  def create
    @destination = current_user.destinations.build(destination_params)
    if @destination.save
      flash[:success] = "Destination added!"
      redirect_to destination_path(@destination)
    else
      render 'destinations/new'
    end
  end

  private

  def destination_params
    params.require(:destination).permit(:name, :expense)
  end
```

```rb
# model
class Destination < ApplicationRecord

  enum expense: {
    "---": 0,
    type1: 1,
    type2: 2,
    type3: 3,
  }
end
```

```rb
# view
<%= form_with model: @destination |f| %>
  <%= f.label :expense %>
  <%= f.select :expense, options_for_select(Destination.expenses), {} %>
  <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

```html
# 出力されたHTML
<select name="destination[expense]">
  <option value="0">---</option>
  <option value="1">type1</option>
  <option value="2">type2</option>
  <option value="3">type3</option>
</select>
```

## 原因の予想

`'1' is not a valid expense` で引数に関するエラーという事なのでbinding.pry で確認したところInteger 型で保存するカラムにString 型で値が送られる事によるエラーでないかと予想しました

```rb
# expense の型を調べる
[1] pry > destination_params[:expense]
"3"
[2] pry > destination_params[:expense].class
String < Object
```

## 試した事

下記を参考にstrong_parameters で保存される値を強制的にInteger 型に変換する方法を試しました

[【Rails】enumを使用したセレクトボックスの実装とDBへの保存 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/y-suna/items/1f5f34c6289fd88199a5)

```rb
# controller
# strong_parameters で:expense をInteger 型に変換
# 修正前
  def destination_params
    params.require(:destination).permit(:name, :expense)
  end

# 修正後
  def destination_params
    params.require(:destination).permit(:name).merge(expense: params[:destination][:expense].to_i)
  end
```

```
# :expense がInteger 型になっているか確認
[1] pry > destination_params[:expense]
Unpermitted parameter: :expense
3
[2] pry > destination_params[:expense].class
Unpermitted parameter: :expense
Integer < Numeric
```

### 試した事で起こった新たな問題

- セレクトボックスのvalue値(1, 2, 3)を保存したいのですが、保存される値がセレクトボックスの選択肢の値(type1, type2, type3)になってしまいます
- schema.rb で:expense の型をInteger 型に指定しているはずなのにDB に保存できてしまう

```
# :expense に保存されている値を確認
[1] pry > destination = Destination.first
{
   :name => "name",
:expense => "type1", # ここにセレクトボックスのvalue値(1, 2, 3)を保存したい
}
[2] pry > destination.expense
"type1"
[3] pry > destination.expense.class
String < Object
```

```
# コントローラの@destination に送られる:expense の値を確認
[1] pry > @destination.expense
"type1"
[2] pry > @destination.expense.class
String < Object
```

### 試した事で分からないこと

- enum で定義した(名前定義: 対応する数値) にどのタイミングで変換されて保存されるのか？
- なぜschema.rb で指定した型以外でもDB に保存できるのか？

## 教えて頂きたいこと

長々と書いてしまったのでまとめます。

- enum で定義した値でセレクトボックスを表示したい
- セレクトボックス選択で保存される値はenum で定義した値のインデックス番号をInteger 型で保存したい

この2点を実現したいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Railsのenumはコードの表記上、文字列(またはシンボル）で透過的に扱えるように実装されています

SQLを直接叩いたり、DBのGUIクライアントを使って保存されたレコード情報を見るとわかりますが実際は文字列ではなく数値が保存されています。あくまでRailsの上ではDBに保存された`1`の値が`type1`と表示されているだけです

Railsで実際に保存された値を確認したい場合はenumを定義した際に利用できる`attribute_before_type_cast`を呼び出すことで確認できます

```
> destination.expense_before_type_cast
=> 1
```

ドキュメント: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast.html

以下のコードは同じ意味となり、enumの値`type1`が代入されます。saveすれば数値の`1`がDBに保存されます

```
> destination.expense = 1
> destination.expense = "type1"
> destination.expense = :type1
```

セレクトボックスのインデックスを保存したい、というのが目的であればenumにしないという選択もあります。現状のままインデックスとしての値が欲しいのであれば `attribute_before_type_cast`を検討してみてください

Comment: 丁寧なコメントありがとうございます。
ちなみにですが今後、投稿に対する検索機能も追加しようと思っているのですがそれを加味した場合だとどんな実装方法が良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問の範囲が広いので明確な回答がし辛いです。また、元の質問から外れてるので別の質問としたほうが良いと思われます。一般的な投稿への検索とした場合はwhere句で問題なく検索できると思います

Comment: 追加の質問の内容に関してはちゃんと整理して別の質問として投稿したいと思います。
enum の質問に関してですが、`db console` で確認したところきちんとenum で定義したインデックス値が保存されていました。
`rails console` で出力されるレコード情報はDB に保存されている値そのものなのだと誤った解釈をしていたことが原因でした。
今後はレコード情報を確認する時は`rails console` ではなく`db console` でSQL を使用して確認するようにしたいと思います。
実装方法に関してですが、検索機能などを加味して`attribute_before_type_cast` を使用するか検討したいと思います。
質問の仕方を含めてとても勉強になりました。丁寧なコメントありがとうございました！